# What are the reflective structures above and to the rear of the engines on a VC-25?

Tags: feature-identification, air-force-one

In [this video at 7:04](https://youtu.be/okz0jI7FN9c?t=424) we see the following view of a VC-25 (an aircraft frequently known as "Air Force One"):

[image: Two VC-25 engines seen from the rear]

What are the two shiny, gold-coloured structures above and to the rear of the engine exhaust?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to a [comment on the video from Jamie Lancaster](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=okz0jI7FN9c&lc=Ugx8YW2LXwNhAZnB_RZ4AaABAg):

> Behind the engines under the wing are the 2 IRCM (Infrared Counter Measure) Jammers - for Air to Air or Ground to Air Missile Defense.

In the comments below, [GremlinWranger suggests](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/93510/what-are-the-reflective-structures-above-and-to-the-rear-of-the-engines-on-a-vc#comment256963_93511) that it's likely a descendant of the [Common Infrared Countermeasures Program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Infrared_Countermeasures_program) based on the appearance of the [ALQ-144](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AN/ALQ-144), which does indeed have similar mirrored panels.

A bit of further searching turns up [this blog entry](https://blog.daum.net/wonhanglee/15861485) which claims to show pictures of the AN/ALQ-157 which is even more similar looking, particularly in its four-facet design with hemispherical coverage. (That page also has a reduced-size German poster explaining "Air Force One," by which they mean the V-25, but the relationship of that to anything else in the article is never explained.)

[image: AN/ALQ-157]

Comment: Not an answer since cannot find a photo to confirm but most likely a descendant of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Infrared_Countermeasures_program, see the appearance of the earlier non LASER version https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AN/ALQ-144

Answer (score 10):

[image]AN/ALQ-204 Matador

https://cryptome.org/eyeball/af1-ircm/af1-ircm.htm

It is a countermeasure system against infrared guided missiles.

It is a descendant of AN/ALQ-144 and similarly is designed to defeat first gen man portable air defence systems(MANPADS)

Comment: There's quite a bit of information in the (excellent) link you gave that would be worth putting in this answer. And this answer isn't really stand-alone yet; it doesn't even mention that this is a missile defense system (it expects readers to know what a MANPAD is to figure that out). If you're willing to expand this to be a stand-alone answer that will briefly explain to people without military knowledge what this is, I'd happily make it my accepted answer. (Or I can expand it if you don't want to.)